# How to make a non clickable button clickable with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, button, redirect

I want a button that is not clickable. But with a javascript you can make it clickable. And when you click you'll get redirected to a page.

Does someone know how to make a button like that?

So I want a button that's not click able. But when a javascript starts you can click it and will get redirected.

PS: And can it be please a php button? If it can be...

Comment: And please can it be a php button? Idk if that can?

Comment: It seems weird but you actually asked the question 4 times. Instead you're supposed to show what you tried and what didn't work etc...

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete working answer, but this will get you started. Run with it!!

```
<button type="button" id="Button">Click Me!</button> 

document.getElementById("Button").disabled = true;

document.getElementById("Button").disabled = false;
```

Take an html5 online tutorial!!